# How to create a custom payment method module

Tags: magento-2.1, php, payment-methods, admin-panel, amazon-payment

I was trying something  new on the payment method where people can upload receipt and it will appear in backend I was thinking  about editing the amazon pay and put my own code to it ,I am totally new to this any one here who can help I will be so damn happy

Comment: To create Custom Payment method please check this links.
https://www.classyllama.com/blog/how-to-create-payment-method-magento-2 , 
https://www.emiprotechnologies.com/technical_notes/magento-technical-notes-60/post/how-to-add-custom-payment-method-in-magento-2-441